# Find consecutive values of pandas with some coditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to find consecutive values of zero and stuck with this problem for a couple of hours.

I have a DataFrame like:

```
Day  |  ID  |  Values
-------------------
1    |  aa  |    0
1    |  aa  |    0
1    |  aa  |    0
1    |  aa  |    0
1    |  aa  |    2.5
1    |  aa  |    2.3
1    |  aa  |    0
1    |  aa  |    0
1    |  aa  |    0
2    |  aa  |    0
2    |  aa  |    0
2    |  aa  |    2.3
2    |  aa  |    0
1    |  bb  |    0
1    |  bb  |    0
1    |  bb  |    0
1    |  bb  |    0
1    |  bb  |    3.5
```

I want to find consecutive values of zeros like this:

```
Day  |  ID  |  Values   | consec_zeros
--------------------------------------
1    |  aa  |    0      |      0
1    |  aa  |    0      |      1
1    |  aa  |    0      |      2
1    |  aa  |    0      |      3
1    |  aa  |    2.5    |      4      # --> there were 4 of consecutive 0s 
1    |  aa  |    2.3    |      0      # 2.5 just destroy consecutive values
1    |  aa  |    0      |      0
1    |  aa  |    0      |      1
1    |  aa  |    0      |      2      
2    |  aa  |    0      |      0      # no 0s before this of Day 2
2    |  aa  |    0      |      1
2    |  aa  |    2.3    |      2
2    |  aa  |    0      |      0
1    |  bb  |    0      |      0     # --> no 0s before this in ID 'bb'
1    |  bb  |    0      |      1
1    |  bb  |    0      |      2
1    |  bb  |    0      |      3
1    |  bb  |    3.5    |      4
```

What I had attempted to do was:

```
g = df['Values'].ne(df['Values'].shift(1)).cumsum()
counts = df.groupby(['ID','Day',g])['Values'].transform('size')
df['consec_zeros'] = np.where(df['Values'].eq(0), counts, 0)
```

Since I'm new to this, please help and point me what I had done wrong.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GroupBy Pandas Count Consecutive Zero's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52752756/groupby-pandas-count-consecutive-zeros)

Comment: @ascripter I alrady looked at that thread but the output of consecutive zeos is not in increment format like my desired output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is main problem add next counter value by first non zero values by [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html), but also use it for thresh, in my solution was added `1` to counter for distinguish first value in counter:

```
g = df['Values'].ne(df['Values'].shift(1)).cumsum()
counts = df.groupby(['ID','Day',g])['Values'].cumcount() + 1
df['consec_zeros'] = np.where(df['Values'].eq(0), counts, 0)

#replace 0 to `NaN`s
a = df['consec_zeros'].mask(df['consec_zeros'].eq(0))
#add 1 to forward filling missing values by limit 1 per groups
df['consec_zeros'] = (np.where(a.isna(), 
                               a.groupby([df['ID'],df['Day']]).ffill(limit=1) + 1, 
                               df['consec_zeros']) - 1)
df['consec_zeros'] = df['consec_zeros'].fillna(0).astype(int)
print (df)
    Day  ID  Values  consec_zeros
0     1  aa     0.0             0
1     1  aa     0.0             1
2     1  aa     0.0             2
3     1  aa     0.0             3
4     1  aa     2.5             4
5     1  aa     2.3             0
6     1  aa     0.0             0
7     1  aa     0.0             1
8     1  aa     0.0             2
9     2  aa     0.0             0
10    2  aa     0.0             1
11    2  aa     2.3             2
12    2  aa     0.0             0
13    1  bb     0.0             0
14    1  bb     0.0             1
15    1  bb     0.0             2
16    1  bb     0.0             3
17    1  bb     3.5             4
```

Comment: Thank you with a good explanation. This really works. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @benji - I think found bug, forwrad filling need per groups, so edited answer.